# Ubuntu Software Center and Update Manager fail to open

Tags: software-center

After attempting to install Google Chrome i386 the installation failed. I then proceeded to the AMD64 to see if it was the problem but...... My computer froze and I forced shut down. Now apport has a message saying

An Error occurred please run Package Manager to fix the problem 
E:the package google-chrome-stable needs to be reinstalled but but i cant find an archive on it) This usually means your packages have unmet dependencies.

Solution anyone PS:Update manager does not work and I don't have Snyaptic.
The file itself failed at the real real end and froze everything but the cursor.

Answer (score 2):

you can always run update via terminal with `sudo apt-get update -f` and then `sudo apt-get -f install` should do it.Download chrome  deb package from their offocial site and install it with gdebi manager( sudo apt-get install gdebi) or sudo dpkg -i /path to chrome.deb .

- **sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq `google-chrome-stable`** ( place name of your package here)

Comment: I am simply trying to get software center and Update Manager to open correctly.The first downloads but a few seconds later it says Ubuntu 12 .04 encountered a problem. The second command you supplied doesn't exist. When I open Software Center it just opens and closes a few seconds later.

Comment: Maybe it will work after you fix broken dependencies so run:                    sudo apt-get update -f ,sudo apt-get-f install. The second command you mean to install gdebi?It s in official repositories i just tried it and it works.Or you mean dpkg -i / here must be your path to deb file with name of package like sudo dpkg -i /home/user/downloads/chrome(name of package).deb

Comment: No as in the sudo apt-get-f-install. The download package is gone except for my browsers download history

Comment: sorry its: sudo apt-get -f install with space _-f after apt-get.. i edited the post ,hope it ll help

Comment: Is their a way to do it without putting in the chrome package as it was deleted from my downloads? I'm very new to Linux. And I did it and this happened E: The package google-chrome-stable needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

Comment: try : sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq google-chrome-stable

Comment: there will be a lot more errors in future so i recommend to make dedicated home partition so every file you have will not be erased with reinstalling system. Bye

Comment: You mean I have to re-install Ubuntu or are you warning me about unrelated upcoming errors that will happen in the future?

Comment: no you dont have to reinstall ubuntu for now its warning about upcoming errors to make your linux experience easier.If system messed up complitely you'll have to reinstall it.Making dedicated /home partition protect user from data loss.All your downloads and settings are saved. By default there is option to use whole drive and install ubuntu and it is erasing everything you have on hard drive.So here is just an advice, as i am new to linux too and making it saved a lot of time to me